# C: fgets skips the first input

Tags: c, xcode, fgets

I use Xcode 7.3 to program on C. I have a problem in my code:

```
 printf("Enter first name: ");
 fflush(stdin);      //here I use getchar() instead of fflush(stdin)
 fgets(temp->firstName, KOL, stdin);
 (temp->firstName)[strlen(temp->firstName)-1]='\0'; 
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("Enter last name: ");
 fflush(stdin);
 fgets(temp->lastName, KOL, stdin);
 (temp->lastName)[strlen(temp->lastName)-1]='\0';
```

Compiler skips input of the first name (fflush(stdin) doesn't help). I found one solution, but it's not the best one: I use getchar() before input of the first name. If you now the reason of this problem and know, how to solve, please help me.

Comment: By the way, those calls to `fflush(stdin)` don't help.  I would take them out.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to `fflush` **`stdout`** instead!

Comment: user3121023, thank You very much)